# How to write a population-growth table in Ada?

Tags: ada

** I want my code to display the following table for the population but it seems that my code is not
even close to this. So how can I make my code right? my biggest problem here is using a range-based
for loop. This table shows the population for A and B and their population growth(in percent) and
asks the  user to enter some data and when the population b bypass population a then the loop should
stop. The sample code:**

```
Enter start year: 1976
Enter country A's population (in million): 200
Enter country A's population increase (in%): 10.0
Enter country B population (in million): 100
Enter country B population increase (in%): 50.0
Year Increase A  Population A  Increase B  Population B
1976  ----        200.00        ------       100.00
1977 20.00        220.00        50.00        150.00
1978 22.00        242.00        75.00        225.00
1979 24.20        266.20        112.50       337.50
In 1979, country B bypassed country A in population.
```

My code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;              use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Population is
x,Population_A, Population_B:Float;
Growth_A, Growth_B, Growth_1,Growth_2: Float;
begin
Put("Write in the year: "); Get(x);
Put("Population_A: "); Get(Population_A);
Put("Population_B: "); Get(Population_B);
Put("Population grow for A: "); Get(Growth_A);
Put("Population growth for B: "); Get(Growth_B); New_Line;

Put("Year   Growth A   Population A   Growth B    Population B ");
for I in 1900..2018 loop
  Put(Integer(I)); New_Line;
  while Population_B < Population_A loop
     Growth_1 := Growth_A +1.0;
     Growth_2 := Growth_B +1.0;
     Put(Growth_1, 13,2,0); New_Line;
     Put(Population_A + (Population_A * Growth_A/100.0),15,2,0); New_Line;
     Put(Growth_2, 17,2,0); New_Line;
     Put(Population_B + (Population_B * Growth_B/100.0),19,2,0);
     end loop;
end loop;
end Population;
```

Comment: In your code, the populations don't grow...

Comment: With a `New_Line` after every value you output, this puts everything on a line of its own, which will not give you a table.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is indeed using a range-based for loop. There are other forms.

I’d probably go for something like

```
--  read in the data
--  check that there is actually a solution
--  (B’s population not already greater than A’s)

Year := -- value read from data, e.g. 1976
loop
   Year := Year + 1;
   Population_Of_A := -- calculate it
   Population_Of_B := -- calculate it
   exit when Population_Of_B > Population_Of_A;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a more complete concept of the problem you are trying to solve.

The problem assumes a constant population growth rate for each country. While this assumption simplifies the problem it is far from realistic.

Either country A or country B could start with the smaller initial population. If the country starting with the smaller population also has the lowest population growth rate the smaller country will never surpass the larger country in population. How will your program deal with the possibility that either country could initially have the larger population?

The following program deals with some of these problems but not all of them. Perhaps you can get an idea how to deal with all the problems by studying the following program.

```
with Ada.Text_Io; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Year : Positive;

   type Country (Id : Character) is record
      Population : Float;
      Rate       : Float;
      Increase   : Float;
   end record;

   type Country_Access is access all Country;

   Country_A : aliased Country('A');
   Country_B : Aliased Country('B');
   Smaller : Country_Access;
   Larger  : Country_Access;

   procedure Display(Yr : Positive; Cnt_A : Country; Cnt_B : Country) is
   begin
      Put(Item => Yr, Width => 4);
      Put(Item => Cnt_A.Increase, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      Put(Item => Cnt_A.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      Put(Item => Cnt_B.Increase, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      Put(Item => Cnt_B.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      New_Line;
   end Display;

begin
   Put("Enter start year: ");
   Get(Year);
   Put("Enter country A's population (in million): ");
   Get(Country_A.Population);
   Put("Enter country A's population increase (in %): ");
   get(Country_A.Rate);
   Country_A.Rate := (Country_A.Rate / 100.0);
   Put("Enter country B's population (in million): ");
   Get(Country_B.Population);
   Put("Enter country B's population increase (in %): ");
   Get(Country_B.Rate);
   Country_B.Rate := (Country_B.Rate / 100.0);
   if Country_A.Population < Country_B.Population then
      Smaller := Country_A'Access;
      Larger := Country_B'Access;
   else
      Smaller := Country_B'Access;
      Larger := Country_A'Access;
   end if;

   Put_Line("Year Increase A Population A Increase B Population B");
   Put(Item => Year, Width => 4);
      Put(" ----------");
      Put(Item => Country_A.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      Put(" ----------");
      Put(Item => Country_B.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
   New_Line;
   while Smaller.Population <= Larger.Population loop
      Year := Year + 1;
      Country_A.Increase := Country_A.Population * Country_A.Rate;
      Country_A.Population := Country_A.Population + Country_A.Increase;
      Country_B.Increase := Country_B.Population * Country_B.Rate;
      Country_B.Population := Country_B.Population + Country_B.Increase;
      Display(Yr    => Year,
              Cnt_A => Country_A,
              Cnt_B => Country_B);
   end loop;
   Put_Line("In" & Year'Image & " country " & Smaller.Id &
              " bypassed country " &
              Larger.Id & " in population.");
end Main;
```

EDIT:
Following is a version of the above program that does not use access types.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;   use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure No_Access is
   Year : Positive;

   type Country is record
      Population : Float;
      Rate       : Float;
      Increase   : Float;
   end record;

   Country_A : Country;
   Country_B : Country;

   procedure Increase
     (Yr : in out Positive; A : in out Country; B : in out Country)
   is
   begin
      Yr           := Yr + 1;
      A.Increase   := A.Population * A.Rate;
      A.Population := A.Population + A.Increase;
      B.Increase   := B.Population * B.Rate;
      B.Population := B.Population + B.Increase;

      Put (Item => Yr, Width => 4);
      Put (Item => A.Increase, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      Put (Item => A.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      Put (Item => B.Increase, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      Put (Item => B.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
      New_Line;
   end Increase;

begin
   Put ("Enter start year: ");
   Get (Year);
   Put ("Enter country A's population (in million): ");
   Get (Country_A.Population);
   Put ("Enter country A's population increase (in %): ");
   Get (Country_A.Rate);
   Country_A.Rate := (Country_A.Rate / 100.0);
   Put ("Enter country B's population (in million): ");
   Get (Country_B.Population);
   Put ("Enter country B's population increase (in %): ");
   Get (Country_B.Rate);
   Country_B.Rate := (Country_B.Rate / 100.0);
   Put_Line ("Year Increase A Population A Increase B Population B");
   Put (Item => Year, Width => 4);
   Put (" ----------");
   Put (Item => Country_A.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
   Put (" ----------");
   Put (Item => Country_B.Population, Aft => 2, Fore => 8, Exp => 0);
   New_Line;
   if Country_A.Population < Country_B.Population then
      while Country_A.Population <= Country_B.Population loop
         Increase (Year, Country_A, Country_B);
      end loop;
      Put_Line
        ("In" & Year'Image & " country A bypassed country B in population.");
   else
      while Country_B.Population <= Country_A.Population loop
         Increase (Year, Country_A, Country_B);
      end loop;
      Put_Line
        ("In" & Year'Image & " country B bypassed country A in population.");
   end if;

end No_Access;
```

Comment: As with all* problems, there is no need for access types here. As this is clearly a beginner's Q, their unnecessary use only serves to make the response less clear. (*First-order approximation)

Comment: It feels like its too complicated for a beginner. I just want it to be done with different loops and simple puts and gets and not with types or accesses.

Comment: I use a record type to help keep track of each country's population, increase, and growth rate. You can do this without a record type, but you still need to use an integer subtype for the year and a floating point type or a fixed point type for the population. You cannot avoid all types.